# Access to elements in xml file and path to them - PERL

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, xslt, xpath

i need to access to all child element in xml which looks like the one below. every element which is not empty, i would like to have its value and path to it. Is anything like this possible ?. I can in xml::simple write manually parsing but it doesn´t feel right.

```
<Incident>
    <Organisation>
      <USD_Local>Secure Cloud Container</USD_Local>
    </Organisation>
    <Location/>
    <Contact_Reference>
      <Organisation>
        <USD_Local>Secure Cloud Container</USD_Local>
      </Organisation>
      <Contact_ID/>
      <Contact_Name>
        <First_Name/>
        <Last_Name/>
      </Contact_Name>
      <External_Reference>AMZZEMP:000000000152299</External_Reference>
      <Freeform_Details/>
      <Email_Address/>
    </Contact_Reference>
    <Requested_By>
      <Organisation>
        <USD_Local>Secure Cloud Container</USD_Local>
      </Organisation>
      <Contact_ID/>
      <Contact_Name>
        <First_Name/>
        <Last_Name/>
      </Contact_Name>
      <External_Reference>AMZZEMP:000000000152299</External_Reference>
      <Freeform_Details/>
      <Email_Address/>
      <Additional_Attribute>Security-AAHPS.Other</Additional_Attribute>
    </Requested_By>
    <Incident_Type>Incident</Incident_Type>
    <Severity>2</Severity>
    <Category>
      <USD_Local>Security-AAHPS.Other</USD_Local>
      <USD_Foreign/>
    </Category>
    <Service_Type>
      <Name/>
      <Target_Duration/>
    </Service_Type>
    <Group>
      <USD_Local>UK.Security.SOC</USD_Local>
    </Group>
    <Configuration_Item action="Add_Link">
      <Name>CATPLD2PRSSEN03</Name>
      <CI_Number/>
      <Serial_Number/>
      <System_Name/>
      <External_Reference/>
      <Additional_Attribute/>
    </Configuration_Item>
    <Summary>Topbanana</Summary>
    <Customer_Reference>SCC</Customer_Reference>
    <Supplier_Reference/>
    <Occurred_Date_Time format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss">2015/04/01 10:50:52</Occurred_Date_Time>
  </Incident>
```

Comment: What module do you use? [XML::Twig](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig) or [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML)?

Comment: for previous xml i used XML::LibXML and XML::Simple ...but manually extract elements doesn´t feel right ... also i use XML::XPath, XML::XPath:.XMLParser

Comment: "*every element which is not empty, i would like to have its value and path to it. Is anything like this possible ?*" Yes, it is possible. Please post the exact code you expect to get as a result. If you have tried anything, post that too. If you haven't, why not?

Comment: I do not have anything written yet except manually parsing with xml::simple.. not great i am just investigating options...                                                                                               my $parser = new XML::Simple;
#parse response:
my $xml =  $parser->XMLin($file);                                                                                                                                                                                                 $xml->{Control_Data}->{Document_Source};

Comment: We need to see your expected output (XML? HTML table? Text?). Also "*element which is not empty*" is ambiguous: is `<Contact_Name>` in your example "empty"? It contains other (empty) elements.

Comment: yes this element is empty, and simple text with value and path would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, it can be dealt with very simply; the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>: "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example XML input, will return:

```
/Incident/Organisation/USD_Local: "Secure Cloud Container"
/Incident/Contact_Reference/Organisation/USD_Local: "Secure Cloud Container"
/Incident/Contact_Reference/External_Reference: "AMZZEMP:000000000152299"
/Incident/Requested_By/Organisation/USD_Local: "Secure Cloud Container"
/Incident/Requested_By/External_Reference: "AMZZEMP:000000000152299"
/Incident/Requested_By/Additional_Attribute: "Security-AAHPS.Other"
/Incident/Incident_Type: "Incident"
/Incident/Severity: "2"
/Incident/Category/USD_Local: "Security-AAHPS.Other"
/Incident/Group/USD_Local: "UK.Security.SOC"
/Incident/Configuration_Item/Name: "CATPLD2PRSSEN03"
/Incident/Summary: "Topbanana"
/Incident/Customer_Reference: "SCC"
/Incident/Occurred_Date_Time: "2015/04/01 10:50:52"
```